# Update User Profile Properties On SharePoint Online Using CSOM API

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365

I have SOA API(service) that will return user profile data from oracle  , I want to update user profile information in share-point online with CSOM like About me , project,Skill experience etc.

here is the sample API
    https://test.oracleoutsourcing.com/api/widget/Dev/GetUserDataOP?userId=30201

Any one help me out to get the user profile data from SOA API service with CSOM .

Thanks !!!

Answer (score -1):

It is possible kindly refer this link for more details. which exactly refer updating about me.

[https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vesku/2014/11/07/sharepoint-user-profile-properties-now-writable-with-csom/]

Upvote if you find useful.